# Oracle SQL help decimal(15,6) on Select

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am having an issue in writing on the SQL for ETL purpose.

My Oracle DB has a `column A` that holds `999999999997259` or `4121.375515`. I need to transform this value to `decimal(15,6)`. The datatype `decimal(15,6)` is on the target where the data will be loaded.

Any suggestions.

TIA

Comment: `999999999997259` won't fit in `DECIMAL(15, 6)`

Comment: `DECIMAL(15, 6)` means "15 digits total, 6 of them after decimal point". You may calculate that the digits amount before decimal point is restricted to 9. `999999999997259` have more than 9 digits before decimal point - so it won't fit in.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the way to round the value to 6 decimal place. Condition: It should contain
valid values.

```
  select cast(round(ColumnaA,6) as DECIMAL(15,6)) from table;
```